# Replacing + with a space

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to set text in a div according to variables in the URL set via GET. I can only do it this way as this is for a JavaScript assignment so no servers around. As URLs tend to do, spaces in a string have been replaced by a `+`.

`str.replace("+"," ")` does absolutely nothing. I found some other links on this site that use a simple `/+/g` instead, but on my code it makes my entire output disappear.

Initial implementation (already replacing %20 with a space for email):
http://imgur.com/TaJo6SA

With the str.replace code:
http://imgur.com/RgmcjnF

Here is the code (function found at css tricks):

```
function getQueryVariable(variable){
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
        for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
        }
        return(false);
   }

    str = getQueryVariable("address");
    var address = address.replace(/+/g," ");
    document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = "Your postal address: " + address;
```

Comment: `str.replace("\\+"," ")`

Comment: `address.replace(/\+/g," ");`

Comment: Take a look to `decodeURIComponent` function

Comment: @KennyLau: in `replace`, the find string can be a *string **or** regexp* ([mozilla ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)). Why would a simple `replace('+', ' ')` fail?

Comment: May be it wasn't fail. Just replace first occurency.

Comment: Aren't you replacing in the wrong variable `address`, instead of `str`?

Comment: I now think that it is not the problem of the replacement...

Comment: @Rad Lexus: Yeah, I was trying some extra stuff before posting and forgot to change it back, hence the str just being left there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify your function:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable){
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
        for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
          var pair = vars[i].split("=");
          if(pair[0] == variable){
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
          }
        }
        return(false);
   }
```

Now it returns parsed data(without any urldecoded parts).

Comment: The regex you posted earlier works. This doesn't seem to have any effect for me. I'll mark it correct I guess since the solution was still by you in another comment?

Comment: Ok, it some other standard (`+` instead of `%20`). I'll update answer.

Comment: I apologize for my noob-ness. We all start somewhere I suppose.
EDIT: Saw your latest comment. Thanks a bunch.